# Draw a Fill Rectangle with low opacity

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, drawing

I a have a PictureBox with a picture in a Windows Form application in C# language.I want draw a FillRectangle in some location of picturebox.but i also need to see picture of picture box.how can i draw this rectangle **with low opacity to see image of picturebox**?

Comment: see question and answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113437/drawing-colors-in-a-picturebox get inspired by those answers you can basically copy paste from there :)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pb.Image))
{
    using(Brush brush = new SolidBrush(your_color))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(brush, x, y, width, height);
    }
}
```

or you can use

```
Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, red, green, blue))
```

where *alpha* goes from 0 to 255, so a value of 128 for your alpha will give you 50%
opactity.

Comment: Like Graphics type, Brush types implement the IDisposable interface. Maybe the example should demonstrate that fact, too.

Comment: You need to consider alpha of color for not solid fill (low opacity).

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a `Graphics` object based on your `PictureBox` image and draw what you want on it:

```
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image);
g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200))
pictureBox1.Refresh()
```

Or as suggested by @Davide Parias you can use Paint event handler:

```
private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 200));
}
```

Comment: in the event handler: private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)...