# Draw Shape in Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, forms, drawing

I am trying to draw a shape with 4 corners. The corner details are given in X and Y co-ordinate (as shown in the Picture below). I tried a method as given by this link: 
[Drawing Colors in a picturebox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1113437/drawing-colors-in-a-picturebox). But the issue is it only for rectangles. [image: Shape with X and Y]

Could any one propose something. I need it basically to generate a swept path (area taken by a car while driving) of the car. So, I get center of the Car in X and Y and the Orientation in degrees. From that I determine the Corner Points of the car in X and Y space. Now I need to show it Visualize it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Rectangle` class along with the `Matrix` class to create a rectangle and then rotate it by your orientation like so:

```
Graphics g = new Graphics()
Rectangle car = new Rectangle(200, 200, 100, 50)
Matrix m = new Matrix()
m.RotateAt(orientation, new PointF(car.Left + (car.Width / 2), car.Top + (car.Height / 2)));
g.Transform = m
g.FillRectangle(Pens.Red, car)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`Graphics.DrawPolygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07e699tw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (or [`Graphics.FillPolygon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0df9swbe(v=vs.110).aspx)) method in the [`OnDraw`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint(v=vs.110).aspx) method of your Form/Control, as follows:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   // If there is an image and it has a location, 
   // paint it when the Form is repainted.
   base.OnPaint(e);
   PointF[] rotatedVertices = // Your rotated rectangle vertices
   e.Graphics.DrawPolygon(yourPen, rotatedVertices);
   // OR
   e.Graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), rotatedVertices);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you know the rotation degree, you can use [`Graphics.RotateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0z3f662%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that. This way you don't need to calculate the corners yourself (guess this implementation is faster).

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(45 /* your degrees here */);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, 10, 10, 200, 100);
}
```

Note that it rotates around `(0;0)`, so you may need to translate it (using [`Graphics.TranslateTransform`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a1d65f4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), too.